# What is the puppet way of invoking RESTful API for populating data in store?

Tags: puppet

I want to populate some data in store. There is RESTful API provided by store. What is the right way in puppet to invoke REST API and populate data in store? Is there any inbuilt mechanism in puppet to invoke the RESTful API? Where should the code be executed, on puppet master or an agent (other than the store)?

Comment: by "store" do you mean the puppetdb database?

Comment: By store, I mean, where the application data is store. For e.g. mongodb.

Comment: No, puppet is not the tool to do that. Puppet is configuration managment tool, not software. You need create the process, script it or make program to do the job, and put the steps (such as install package, set config file, and manage the service status) in puppet code.